# Do I need a transit visa for Morocco?

Tags: visas, transit, morocco, egyptian-citizens, casablanca

I am travelling from Montreal, Canada to Cairo, Egypt transitting in Casablanca for 13 hours. Have a hotel voucher. I hold a valid Egyptian passport and a 5 year valid visa to Canada and US. Do I need a transit visa for Casablanca touring for 12 hours?
Having a hotel voucher from the carrier company Royal Air Maroc, to compensate for the long lay over, I have to move out of the airport premises. Then am I in need for a transit visa?

Answer (score 3):

**You'll need a visa only if you want to leave the airport.**

> National Egypt (EG)             /Transit Morocco (MA)
>   Destination Egypt (EG)
>
> Visa required, except for Children under 17 years of age of
>   any nationality , if having Moroccan parent(s) and being registered in parent's passport
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): ...
>   Visa required, except for Holders of confirmed onward tickets
>   for a max. transit time of 24 hours at
>   Casablanca (CMN)

Since your layover is under 24 hours, you can transit without a visa if you stay in the airport, but you'll need a visa if you want to enter Morocco.

Source: [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=EG&TR=CMN&DE=CAI&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C)

Comment: However the OP can not leave the airport without a visa, right? I believe that is part of their question.

Comment: @mts Thanks for pointing that out; I've updated my answer accordingly. (When I posted my initial answer, the question didn't mention leaving the airport.)

Comment: Where does it say that you can't leave the airport? That's how TWOV works in the Schengen area or Turkey but not in China for example. Even the UK has a transit without visa concession that allowed some travellers to go through immigration to spend the night at a hotel while on transit until very recently (it was removed at the end of 2014).

Comment: @Relaxed Timatic's TWOV definition says 
"Unless stated otherwise, passengers wishing to TWOV must... remain in the transit area (airside) or on the aircraft," so I assumed that, if TWOVers were allowed to leave the airport at CMN, the Timatic page would have said so.

Comment: @HaigNakashian If an answer provided answers your question, feel free to "accept" it by clicking the green check mark! Thanks